# Response: {"error":"Undefined index: fieldGroup"}

Tags: projectconfig, project.yaml

I've recently had to handle a massive merge on a Craft project which resulted in many conflicts in the `project.yaml` file. I tried to clean up the merge conflicts as best as I can.

And now I have this error:

[image]

Question now is there a way to recover or re-generate the `project.yaml`?

Also, this my first experience working with Craft in a team. Any suggestions on best approach to keep `project.yaml` clean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can rebuild your `project.yaml` by running `./craft project-config/rebuild`.

In terms of workflow [here's a good article](https://medium.com/@ben_45934/understanding-project-config-in-craft-cms-3dd70b232dfa) that discusses it.